# Error with using text/template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I'm doing a todo list on backbone. But I have an error when I'm using text/template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="stats-template"></script>
```

in my index.html.

An error is : **This inspection checks for duplicate "id" attributes in XML.** 
How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe other element in your html has the same "id"?

Comment: I've used 2 different id.

Comment: Do you have only two id's defined on your page?

Comment: Oh god. Yeah, you are right. I've used the same id in my code) I didnt replace this code <script type="text/template" id="stats-template"></script> on my template and use it two times...) All is ok now, thanks!)